# In app Purchase issue in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have successfully  test product id (i.e android.test.purchased etc.) in my app but I am getting exception with real product id..any help will be appreciate.
I have also published inappproduct list with draft application.

I am getting Below exception::::

```
11-18 15:33:15.367: E/Volley(20873): [12] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/purchase
11-18 15:33:15.378: W/Finsky(20873): [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse: DisplayErrorMessage[The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.]
11-18 15:33:15.382: D/Volley(20873): [11] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=inapp:com.inappdemo:s1 NORMAL 232> [lifetime=3146], [size=727], [rc=200], [retryCount=1]
11-18 15:33:15.386: E/Finsky(20873): [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, message=The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem setting up my phone main Google account as test account:
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should add yourself as a test account to your publisher account. 
Don't forget that you can't purchase from yourself (test account should be different from publisher account)

Comment: Well.. thanks for that information!  Gee.. would have been nice to know before I spent two days banging my head against a wall.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you have not activated your `APK`. Just activate your `APK`..then it will be in `Ready to Publish` state. Now your `APK` in Drafts.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, for my app, this error was caused by setting the `price` field to $0.00 on the Developer Console.  Even though Google states the price cannot be less than $0.99, they still allow you to set the price to $0.00, and then give this enigmatic error.