# Android in-app Billing unexpected response

Tags: android, billing, in-app, merchant-account

I'm trying to implement android's In app billing Dungeon project.

when i try to purchase items i entered i keep getting:

06-04 10:37:33.343: E/Volley(1913): [228] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/completePurchase
06-04 10:37:33.343: W/Finsky(1913): [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse: DisplayErrorMessage[Your order could not be processed. Please try again.]
06-04 10:37:33.343: E/Finsky(1913): [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, message=Your order could not be processed. Please try again.

I set items in the In-app products and published them

I signed the app and uploaded the signed app to Google play and to the device via adb.
-- same error
I tried to publish the app and then download it to the device
-- same error

The error pops after I press "Accept & Buy"

My thought is that it could have something to do with my Google merchant account, any Ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: I got the same thing :) any idea what it was in the end?

Comment: the problem was solved after I created a new Merchant account

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477005/in-app-billing-not-working-your-request-could-not-be-processed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've setup your phone's account as a test account, and that your test account isn't the same as your Google Checkout merchant account (since you can't by from yourself):

Similar question: [In app Purchase issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182272/in-app-purchase-issue-in-android)

*Note that, at the time of writing, there's a bug where new test accounts don't always get added to old applications. You can quickly publish/unpublish your app as a workaround, as this will disable the test-account requirement. Alternatively, you could test using the versionCode for a published version of your app that already has in-app billing enabled.*

Comment: Is this still a bug, or has it been fixed? I'm wondering if it's something else.