# In-App billing not working (Your request could not be processed)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Today I published my app, and when my friend tried to buy the in-app content the market says: "Your request could not be processed. please try again".

A few clarifications:

1. The app was published more than 10 hours ago, and is visible in the google play store.
2. The testing with google static codes DID work all the time
3. The buying account is NOT the publisher account
4. Most of the code is copied as is from google's in-app billing example
5. The in-app product IS shown correctly when trying to buy.
6. The buyer has a valid credit card

Thanks!

Comment: Does the buyer have enough money to buy the content?

Comment: Of course... I will add it to the clarifications list :)

Comment: Any debug or error messages in your Android Developer Console?  ( URL such as https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=.... )

Comment: Is the buyer account the primary account?

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem since then? If not, is it possible that there a version mismatch between the release version on your friend's phone and than the one on Google Play?

Comment: Not yet solved... No. the versions match

Comment: Add log-entries to your buying/response-routine, update the app on Google Play, and ask your friend to send you a log-output with aLogcat. This should provide you with a more detailed error than simply "Your request could not be processed"

Comment: Please update this question with an answer if you have one...

Comment: Still no answer... I think I am going to give up :(

Comment: Dealing with the same issues here man. Keep it up and let us all know if you figure it out.

Comment: Can you post the output from `adb logcat` when you're trying to make the purchase? There may be more useful information there.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you have to consider.

1. Check the **public key** [Must be your account public key.]
2. Check if your friend is in the test account list for that product.(Remove it)
3. In your code use logcat to find the status code. (Use billing receiver for any purchase request code). or Error : **Developer Error.**
4. Be sure you are signing with correct **keystore**.

FYI onRequestPurchaseResponse() inside **Dungeon.java** get the Response.

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you from one of the accepted countries for In App Purchases by Google Play?
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324