# CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code =-1, message = Error Processing Purchase [DF-BPA-13]

Tags: android, in-app-billing

So I'm using the android billing library and have this little setup:

```
    BillingController.setConfiguration(new BillingController.IConfiguration() {

                    public byte[] getObfuscationSalt() {
//Havent changed this
                        return new byte[] { 41, -90, -116, -41, 66, -53, 122,
                                -110, -127, -96, -88, 77, 127, 115, 1, 73, 57,
                                110, 48, -116 };
                    }

                    public String getPublicKey() {
                        return "The key (yes this is set correctly)";
                    }
                });

        BillingController.setDebug(true);

        mBillingObserver = new AbstractBillingObserver(this) {

            public void onBillingChecked(boolean supported) {
                BuyCoins.this.onBillingChecked(supported);
            }

            public void onPurchaseStateChanged(String itemId,
                    PurchaseState state) {
                BuyCoins.this.onPurchaseStateChanged(itemId, state);
            }

            public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(String itemId,
                    ResponseCode response) {
                BuyCoins.this.onRequestPurchaseResponse(itemId,
                        response);
            }

            public void onSubscriptionChecked(boolean supported) {
                BuyCoins.this.onSubscriptionChecked(supported);
            }

        };

        BillingController.registerObserver(mBillingObserver);
        BillingController.checkBillingSupported(this);
        BillingController.checkSubscriptionSupported(this);

    }
```

And then simply:

```
public void onSubscriptionChecked(boolean supported) {
    if (supported) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Subscription is supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Subscription is NOT supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}

public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(String itemId, ResponseCode response) {
    if (response == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Response OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else if (response == ResponseCode.RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Response Canceled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (response == ResponseCode.RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Response Unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (response == ResponseCode.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Response Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "UNKNOWN RESPONSE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();        }
}

public void onPurchaseStateChanged(String itemId, PurchaseState state) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Purchase State: " + state.toString() + " for item " + itemId,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    purchaseList();
}

public void onBillingChecked(boolean supported) {
    if (supported) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Billing is supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Billing is NOT supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

And the item is called with:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buy_coins_button_one:
        BillingController.requestPurchase(this, "coins",true /* confirm */, null);
        break;
    case R.id.buy_coins_button_two:
        BillingController.requestPurchase(this, "android.test.purchased",true /* confirm */, null);
        break;

    }

}
```

If I hit Button One (the coins), I get the error mentioned in the title ("Error Processing Purchase: [DF-BPA-13] before I can even hit "accept and buy"

I've checked everywhere and there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as to why this error comes about.

If I hit Button Two (the reserved android one), I am able to hit buy but then I get:

Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]

So here are some steps taken to combat this nonsense:

- Public Key is correct
- In-app item has been published for 1 day
- Debug is set to true on the billing observer
- App has been exported and signed with the keystore, and apk installed
- Testing user IS NOT publishing user
- Testing user is on list of test accounts
- Debug was set to off with same issues
- Main phone user has been changed (Factory Reset) to different test users
- Tested on different devices with different users
- Version and Version code on APK and Market are the same

I'm completely lost here. Maybe its worth noting that theres another error ([27] as opposed to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182272/in-app-purchase-issue-in-android) like the others): `[27] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramsnMy695NrbaHSHjK0hNnMgg' failed!`

Am I missing something somewhere? It all seemed very straightforward.

I have looked at:

[In App Purchase Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182272/in-app-purchase-issue-in-android)

[[DF-BPA-13]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1768975)

[In-App Billing Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477005/in-app-billing-not-working-your-request-could-not-be-processed)

I'll keep you updated on how I figure it out because it seems to be a regular issue

Edit: So you can't remove apps from your dev console so removing/adding didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HA got it. This was strange. Maybe it was a fluke and it just kicked in, but this worked for me:

Turns out the test account and the publisher account were tied to the same credit card on checkout. Changing it on the test account fixed it up. Grrrrr.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically because of Google needs some time to sync product list. So if you make any change to your product or add new item then give some time (an 1 hour or so) it will be fixed automatically

Comment: This wasn't the issue at all if you read: "In-app item has been published for 1 day"